# Why is IDEone showing runtime error even after getting the output?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

What is wrong with my program ?
It works fine on my PC but in IDEone it gives the correct output but shows **runtime error**. Please help.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    int vote;
};


int main()
{
  int t;
  cin>>t;

  while(t--)
  {
      int count=0;
      int n;
      cin>>n;
      vector <int> a(n);
      student s[n];
      int k;
      cin>>k;

      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
           s[i].vote=0;
      }


      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
           cin>>a[i];
      }
      int temp=0;

      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
          if(a[i] != i)
          {
              temp=a[i];
              s[temp].vote++;
          }
      } 

      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
          if(s[i].vote==k)
          {
              count++;
          }
      }

          printf("%d\n",count);

         }
return 0;
}
```

This is the error shown in IDEone :-

> Error in `./prog': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x085cca10

Comment: Try entering -4 as the input and see what happens. :-)  Also, enter -2 as the next parameter.

Comment: Looks like a good subject to use a debugger.  Step through the code and determine which statement is causing the issue.  Let us know which statement is the culprit.

Comment: BTW, Variable Length Arrays (VLA) are not a C++ thing (the statement `student s[n]`.  Use a `std::vector` or *dynamically allocate the memory using `operator new`*.

Comment: I tried debugging but I don't think any statement is causing the error. In my PC the output is displayed without any error. I think that **student s[n]** causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  student s[n];
```

This declares an array called `s`. It contains `n` values. The values are `s[0]` through `s[n-1]` (you can count them all on your fingers, if you'd like, using a small number of `n`, such as 5).

```
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
       s[i].vote=0;
  }
```

This attempts to initialize values `s[1]` through `s[n]`. The only problem is that `s[n]` doesn't exist. The last value in the array is `s[n-1]`. This code will corrupt memory on the stack, resulting in undefined behavior.

The same bug also occurs with the `a` array.

Comment: Because this bug results in "undefined behavior". Undefined behavior means: any result can happen. This includes: 1) correct output; 2) correct output followed by a crash; 3) completely random, incorrect output; 4) your computer catches fire; 5) the same thing that almost happened in Ghostbusters (1984): all life as you know it stopping instantaneously and every molecule in your body exploding at the speed of light. Any of these meets the definition of "undefined behavior".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik LOL #5 actually happened to my friend. ;p

Answer (score 0):

The index values for both `vector` and array are zero based and goes up to `n - 1`. So

```
for(int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
```

would be better.

Now you write one element too far, which `free` finds out later when the data after the memory block is invalid.